# How to append a Header value from file as a extra column in csv file using pyspark for 1000 files

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been trying to filter out a header line with **#Id** in the beginning and add the `id number` as a column to the **file_name** being processed. Below are sample files to be processed

**File 1:**

```
#sample first line
#Id: abcdef
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
2,3,3
4,5,6
```

**File 2:**

```
#sample first line
#Id: ghjklo
col1,col2,col3
5,1,3
2,5,8
8,0,4
```

When I try to construct the dataframe and print the results I am able to add the filename as a column using the below snippet.

```
par_df = spark.read.schema(schema) \
                    .option("header", "true") \
                    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
                    .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")\
                    .csv("s3a://" + bucket "/"+prefix+"/").withColumn("FileName", func.input_file_name())
```

This filters out the header info and below is the snippet to print the result.

```
parsed_diff_df = par_df.select(
    par_df['col1'],
    par_df['col2'])    
parsed_diff_df.registerTempTable("parsed_diff_df_table")
results = sqlContext.sql("select col1, col2, FileName from "                        
                             "parsed_diff_df_table").collect()
```

This is the result I have got and unable to append the Id column as it is already filtered out.

```
1,2,3,File1
2,3,3,File1
4,5,6,File1
5,1,3,File2
2,5,8,File2
8,0,4,File2
```

Intended result is below.

```
1,2,3,abcdef,File1
2,3,3,abcdef,File1
4,5,6,abcdef,File1
5,1,3,ghjklo,File2
2,5,8,ghjklo,File2
8,0,4,ghjklo,File2
```

I have also tried this but no luck.

```
   rdd = sc.textFile("s3a://" + bucket + "/"+prefix+"/").flatMap(lambda line: line.split("\n")).filter(lambda line: '#' in line)

   results = rdd.collect()
   for row in results:
       print row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the `FileName` of each file to it's `id`:

Let's write a function to extract the id value:

```py
import re
def extract_id(l):
    return re.search('#Id: ([a-z]+)\\n', line).group(1)
```

Let's read the files as RDDs:

```py
file_id = sc.wholeTextFiles("/user/at967214/test.csv").filter(lambda l: l[1][0]=='#').map(lambda l: [l[0], extract_id(l[1])])
```

And now the dataframe:

```py
file_id_df = spark.createDataFrame(file_id, ["FileName", "id"])
```

Now you can join it with your first dataframe

```py
par_df.join(file_id_df, "FileName", "inner")
```

Comment: file_id_df = spark.createDataFrame(file_id, ["FileName", "id"])
 How do you get the file name to append in the second dataframe?

Comment: Like you did with function `input_file_name`. I used your `par_df` dataframe

Comment: The FileName column is for par_df dataframe and how could you use the FileName column for that df to use in file_id_df

Comment: How is l[0] fileName, how did you filter and acheived that

Comment: `WholeTextFiles` appends the name of the file when reading it as a RDD just like `.withColumn("FileName", func.input_file_name())` does for dataframes. I filtered on lines starting with a `#` because these were your comment lines (basically any comment even if it spreads on several lines at the beginning of a file will end up in the first row of the RDD). I used a regex to extract just the part I wanted, assuming the `Id` is only composed of letters and voilà! :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using csv loader, implement below steps to achieve this:

- Load data to pair rdd using sparkContext.wholeTextFiles.
- Apply flatMapValues function

  1. Split each record using new line '\n'
  2. Get id from first line-->split first line using ':' then second part of split as id.
  3. Skip second line as schema is predefined.
  4. line 3rd to last line append id.
- apply map function skip key as it is contains file name and split value to individual columns-->split using ','.
- Convert RDD to dataset using 'col1, col2, col3'

I am java developer, not much handson with Python, something similar might help you:

```
pairRdd=sc.wholeTextFiles('<path>')

#it exactly wont work, make required changes:
def appendId( record ):
   splits = record.splitlines()
   id=splits[0].split(':')[1].strip()
   print(id)
   output=[]
   for s in xrange(2,len(splits)):
       output.append(splits[s]+','+id)
   return output
objRDD=pairRdd.flatMapValues(appendId)
.map(lambda key,val:val.split(','))
.map(lambda p:Row(col1=int(p[0]), col2=int(p[1])........FileName=p[3]))
dataframe=spark.createDataFrame(objRdd)
.....
```

**Equivalent Java:**

```
JavaPairRDD<String[]> inputRdd = sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("<xyz path>");;
    inputRdd.flatMapValues(new Function<String, Iterable<String>>() {
                               @Override
                               public Iterable<String> call(String v1) throws Exception {
                                   String[] splits = v1.split( System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                   String id = splits[0].split(":")[1].trim();
                                   List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
                                   for (int i =2;i<splits.length;i++){
                                       values.add(String.format("%s,%s", splits[i],id));
                                   }
                                   return values;
                               }
                           }
    ).map(s->s._2().split(","));
```

Comment: could you please post a snippet?